UK visit visa application for a self employed
I own a tailoring outlet (self employed sole business owner) it is registered and operated with a company account.
please how do i go about the financial aspect when applying for a visitors visa to the UK.  do i pay myself monthly salary do i just show my savings account. or show an account that only shows savings towards the trip

Keep your business and private accounts separate. Pay yourself a monthly salary for at least 6 months. Provide a tax return that  supports your declared income.

Ok. Thank you. But do I give them the bank statement for the business or just the personal account that shows salary received. And then a tax return for the business.

You give them bank statements for both, without both UKVI can’t get an understanding of your overall circumstances. Give them financial accounts for the business that show it’s profitable and that those profits are comfortably sufficient to cover the monthly salary you pay yourself.

Ok. Thank you. This is really helpful. So I was also thinking of writing a self employed introduction letter and another personal self introductory letter just so things are clearly explained. What do you think. Plus I will love it if you have any hands free advices generally. I will be traveling with my wife she has a running visa and she is funding her own trip and we also have a new born baby less than a year.

I’ve no idea what a ‘running visa’ is, and IMHO one covering letter is sufficient (ECOs are busy and don’t want to wade through unnecessary paperwork). To get a UK visa you’ll need to demonstrate a good travel history, adequate and proportionate savings, and a compelling reason to return home, which can be hard to do if you’re intending to travel with your entire family. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e

Sorry that was a typo. I meant my wife is a frequent traveler especially to the uk. And presently has a 10year Visa. We got married in 2021. I have never traveled out of my country. She has applied for our daughter under her own name. Our daughter is presently 6months old. What best approach do you think I should take if you were to advice. I have already been refused twice. One on the basis of my finance not been clear to them and that they were not sure at the time I was genuinely married to my wife. 2nd time was on a silly mistake on my part. Forgot to add a sponsors account statement.
